# A Python script, a proxy and Microsoft Forefront - Auto-Authentication

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, proxy, ldap

Today I'm dealing with a Python3 script that has to do a http post request and send a mail.

The Python script is launched on a Windows PC that is in a corporate network protected by Forefront.
The user is logged with his secret credentials and can access to the internet through a proxy.

Like the other non-Microsoft applications (i.e. Chrome), I want my script to connect to the internet without prompt the user for his username and password.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Update your question with your current code and any errors you get. Have you already tried configuring a [proxy using the requests library?](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies)

Comment: Yes, I've already tried many solutions. None of them worked.
I've tried request (with proxy and auth) and urllib3. At the moment I don't have a working code.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Is it just prompting for username and password?

Answer (score 1):

On Microsoft OSes, the authentication used is Kerberos, so you won't be able to use directly your ID + password.

I'm on Linux, so I can't test it directly but I think that you can create a proxy with fiddler which can negociate the authentication for you, and you can use this proxy with python.

Fiddler's Composer will automatically respond to authentication challenges (including the Negotiate protocol which wraps Kerberos) if you tick the Authentication box on the Options subtab, in the menus.

Comment: I'd like to see some working code of a connecting Python program, just how chrome does automatically...